# How do I stop the border from breaking apart when zooming in?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, border

http://mistcave.com/temp/

Zoom into the page and scroll right. The 1px black border at the bottom of the header is cut off a bit short. How do I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Even Stack Overflow suffers this problem. Except it's with the `background-color` when resized smaller: http://i.imgur.com/9sA7d5C.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a dirty hack. Tough it work flawlessly.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mwhR/)

```
#wrap {
    width: 100%;
}

#header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I cleaned up your hack a bit. Here's the result.

http://mistcave.com/temp/

Answer (score 2):

put the border bottom property in your header div

also to note if you are using google chrome you can go to select elements and view the dimensions of each div which will help you trouble shoot in the future

Comment: Putting the border in the header div won't allow me to extend it to the rest of the page since I have the width on that div limited to 1200px.

I use FireFox, has a similar feature. Very useful!

Comment: Basically your wrapper is smaller than the divs it contains you need to set a width and height for it. The header is overflowing and the portion of the header div not being contained is not being underlined.

you can set your wrapper to a width of 1200 px and your header div to a width of 100%, it should keep it inside of the wrapper and give you the spacing you want

Answer (score 0):

set the width of the #wrap in CSS to be 100%

OR simply do the following:

```
body
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.extendfull, .extendleft
{
    padding-left: 3000px;
    margin-left: -3000px;
}
.extendfull, .extendright
{
    padding-right: 3000px;
    margin-right: -3000px;
}
```

overflow-x: hidden prevents horizontal scrolling, and increasing the padding is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't really matter. Because the Border-bottom effect follows the size of your browser. No web users would zoom in and out pages except you.

It will also be fine in every screensize, just don't zoom it in and out. 
That thing is fine every site has that problem too but it's not a big deal.